# How to loop through the controls created dynamically on pageload

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, dynamic-controls

I have created controls dynamically inside asp table which is inside asp panel.

`tblDynamicRecPatrn` is asp table and `pnlRecPatrn` is the panel. asp table is inside panel and inside table are the controls created dynamically.

I have done the following code to loop through the controls but its not finding the controls created dynamcally.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tblDynamicRecPatrn.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (tblDynamicRecPatrn.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(RadioButton))
    {
        RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
        rb = (RadioButton)tblDynamicRecPatrn.Controls[i];
    }
}
```

The above code returned me `tblDynamicRecPatrn.Controls.Count` as 2 and the `tblDynamicRecPatrn.Controls[i].GetType()` was table and a literal.

I replaced `tblDynamicRecPatrn` with `pnlRecPatrn` in the code and i got the count as 3, with 2 of them as literal and one as table.

instead if i loop as `foreach (Control control in Controls)` than i can find the dynamic controls

Can anyone help me sort out as to why i am not able to find the controls created dynaically.

Comment: Any dynamically created control should be re-created on the `Page_Init` method, in order to be added to the control tree and have the viewstate binded to it. Also, of course, always use the same `ID`.

Comment: @AndreCalil Yes i know about that, also that i can find these controls if i do `foreach (Control control in Controls)` i want to know why i cant find it inside panel or inside asp table

Comment: Try looping through the controls of the panel, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should loop through the controls recursively

```
Func<System.Web.UI.ControlCollection, IEnumerable<System.Web.UI.Control>> FlattenControls = null;
FlattenControls = coll => coll.Cast<System.Web.UI.Control>()
                            .Concat(coll.Cast<System.Web.UI.Control>()
                                        .SelectMany(x => FlattenControls(x.Controls))
                            );


var radioButtons = FlattenControls(this.Controls).OfType<RadioButton>().ToList();
```